# Subgradient of Ky Fan norm

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, subgradient, matrix-norms

Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, its Ky Fan $k$-norm is defined as the sum of largest $k$ singular values. How can I find a sub-gradient of this norm?

I tried normal sub-gradient properties that are part of a convex optimization course, but I am not able to derive one subgradient of this norm.

Comment: See Section 3 in [On matrix approximation problems with Ky Fank norms](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02210386)

Comment: Thanks @GabrielRomon. Good to know that it is a well studied problem. But it is kind of confusing. I am not able to understand the notation. New parameter s and t appear suddenly. Don't understand why both are needed. One time read did not break it for me. From a first read, i think we wiill need knowledge of multiplicity of each singular values. I will read it couple of times more. I will try and post what I feel the answer is for 3 by 3 case.

Comment: Find a subgradient for each of the $i$th singular values and add them.

Comment: @copper.hat Are you saying I need to find the sub-gradient of largest singular value function, then sub-gradient of second largest singular value function and so on. And add them to get the sub-gradient of Ky Fan-k norm. How can I justify this. Are you saying this is same as the answer given in the reference given by  Gabriel

Comment: @copper.hat How do you find sub-gradient for each of the $i^{th}$ singular values.